# Why is decltype'ing members of the parent class forbidden if it's a template?

Tags: c++, templates, language-design

Why are members of a base class not available in a derived class if the base is templated in the derived?

At compile time all of the types should be instantiated, so I don't see what or why it is different.  I can see an argument for this being able to create unresolvable types; but, that feels like a compile time error, not a restriction to the language.

More explicitly, why does this work?

```cpp
template<typename T>
class A{
protected:
   int member;
};

class B: public A<int>{
   decltype(member) another_member;
};
```

But, this doesn't?

```cpp
template<typename T>
class A{
protected:
   int member;
};

template<typename T>
class B: public A<T>{
   decltype(member) another_member;
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an ISOCPP FAQ for this question.

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members

and read the next one too about how it can silently hurt you

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-silent-bug

Basically the compiler will not look into templated base classes. The reason is likely that the concrete class does not exist at that point.

The previous example works because `A<int>` is a concrete class while `A<T>` is not. For the same reason you are forced to add `typename` to arguments and members.

You should put the scope back as in

```
decltype(B::member)
```

---

Warning: Don't use this.

```
decltype(A<T>::member)
```

This will temporarily silence the warning until a `B` is instantiated; but, won't work unless `B<T>` is a friend of `A<T>`, since `B` can't access `A<T>`'s protected members though that name.

Comment: `decltype(A<T>::member)` doesn't seem to work since `member` was protected

Comment: `A<T>::member`  does work in godbolt - https://godbolt.org/z/f5oo3voea

Comment: It doesn't if you make a `B`, the error is just latent.  https://godbolt.org/z/Mr5oqKn4q