# Why are access specifiers treated differently when expanding template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, language-design

Expanding on the question "[Why is decltype'ing members of the parent class forbidden if it's a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70149710)".

Both Clang and GCC complain that `B` can't access `A::member`, because it is protected.

But, `B` can access `A::member` if a particular instance of `B` is asked, it's only during the expansion of `B<int>::type_name` that the error arises.

Why is the public inheritance of `A` by `B` ignored in this context? (If that's what's happening.)

```cpp
template<typename T>
class A{
protected:
   int member;
public:
   using type_name = T;
};

template<typename T>
class B: public A<T>{
   decltype(A<T>::member) another_member;
};

template<typename T,
         typename P=typename T::type_name>
void foo(){}

// Force the instantiation of foo
void bar(){
    foo<B<int>>();
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. `B<T>` is allowed to access `A<T>::member` through an instance of `B<T>` or with `B<T>::` qualified name. `decltype(A<T>::member)` does neither so it is an error. Why do you expect otherwise?

Comment: My confusion was related to the previous question.  The provided error makes more sense with new eyes.  I've updated the previous question's answer to reflect this incorrectness.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with templates. https://godbolt.org/z/1xK4bM6bK

Comment: Related (but not duplicate a priori): [why-is-decltype-not-allowed-on-private-member-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924217/why-is-decltype-not-allowed-on-private-member-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They'er not.  Use `B<T>::member`.

---

The trouble comes from, in `decltype(member)` the compiler imminently notices that `member` isn't in scope; however, in `decltype(A<T>::member)` the compiler can't tell that the member is protected until template expansion.  Leading to a (mostly) unrelated stack of template expansion information in the error.

Since `B<T>` is not a `friend` of `A<T>` it can't access its `protect`ed members through its name; but instead should access them though its qualified name of `B<T>::member`.

Comment: In a class template, members of a dependent base class are never in scope.

Comment: So they aren't, I should have checked that first.  Edited.

Comment: `B::member` also works.